# Inferior-lisp not responding on sldb-quit

Tags: common-lisp, slime

I just started learning common lisp, so excuse me if lisp terminology is a bit off. I installed slime and am using Clozure CL. ccl is working just fine. When I enter a wrong expression, the debugger opens (`slbc ccl/1` buffer). When I enter `q`, the debugger buffer closes, and then the `inferior-lisp` buffer does not respond. Why is that? 
and if I want to continue work, I seem to have to restart `inferior-lisp`, what is it I am doing wring?

Comment: In slime you shouldn't write in the inferior-lisp buffer but in the slime-repl. Are you entering expressions in the inferior-lisp-buffer?

Comment: @PuercoPop i am afraid i am. how do i open a repl buffer?

Comment: It should open automatically after M-x slime (I use sly don't remember the exact same name)

Comment: when i open M-x slime, i get a `infirior-lisp` and a `lisp-events` buffer. not a slime-repl

Comment: I just check in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kskJKkb4DDQ and it is indeed named *slime-repl...*. I have no idea why you don't get one. How did you install slime? Through quicklisp?

Comment: I install it through MELPA repository, folowing the instructions: https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Installation.html#Installation

Comment: The problem was with the setup..
i should have included a (slime-setup ;;options) in the .emacs file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wanted to say put out the solution I found.

I had followed the instructions in the slime's user manual ([from here](https://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Installation.html#Installation)), I used MALPA repository to install slime.

As PuercoPop's says in the comments, i should land in a `slime-repl` buffer, which I didn't have by default. I did some further digging and learnt that i have to add a few more line to my .emacs file for the `slime-repl` buffer to load. The line needed was

```
(slime-setup '(slime-fancy))
```

My final .emacs file looks like this:

```
(require 'package)
(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/"))
(when (< emacs-major-version 24)
  (add-to-list 'package-archives '("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(package-initialize)
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq inferior-lisp-program "F:/Binaries/ccl/wx86cl64.exe")
(setq slime-auto-connect 'ask)
(setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
(require  'slime)
(slime-setup
 '(slime-fancy slime-asdf slime-references slime-indentation slime-xref-browser)
)
```

Comment: I didn't knew that Slime recommended MELPA. `(ql:quickload "quicklisp-slime-helper")` is better imho as it keeps 'in sync' with changes to lisp implementations (such as a the backquote representation last year). Also you can use one setq with mulitple pairs. Happy Lisping!